# Insert ID from radio button value into database using Ajax and jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have created an ordering system, using ajax, but I have a problem sending the id from the ajax page to the database.

Using the code below for the HTML part, the jquery part and the ajax part, I hope to come up with a solution.

So first up is the HTML part. This lists all the items due for delivery for a particular distributor. The distributors id is saved in the session.

```
<td class="main" width="10%"><a href="#" id="orderAllocate"><img src="images/users.png" width="25" height="25" border="0" alt=""></a></td>
```

Clicking on this button opens up a jQuery dialog box with all the different employees for the distributor. Code is as follows:

```
$("a#orderAllocate").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

if($("#Allocate").length > 0) {
    $("#Allocate").remove();
}

$("<div id='Allocate' title='Please Allocate The Order'></div>").dialog({
    autoOpen: true, 
    width:350,
    height:360,
    resizable: false,
    stack: true,
    modal: true,
    open: function(event, ui) {

        $('#Allocate').load("ajax.php?action=allocate_delivery", function (){
            $(this).find('button').button();
        });


         $("#CancelAllocation").button({icons: {primary: "ui-icon-close"}}).live ("click", function() {

            $( "#Allocate" ).dialog('close');

       });


    }

});

});
```

The ajax part is :

```
$html = '';

 $allocate_query = tep_db_query("select * from ".  TABLE_DRIVERS ." where distributor_id='" . (int)$distributor_id . "'");


    $html .= '<form id="save_designation">

            <table>      
                <tr>';

 while($allocate = tep_db_fetch_array($allocate_query)){

                $html .= '<ul id="selectable">
                        <li class="ui-state-default"><input type="radio" name="select_driver" value="'.$allocate['driver_id'].'">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="./images/arrow_green.gif" alt="" border="0" height="12" width="15">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$allocate['driver_firstname'].' '.$allocate['driver_surname'].'<br></li>
                    </ul>';

 }

                '</tr>
            </table>';



    $html .= '<br>

              <table>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left"><button id="CancelAllocation" type="button">Cancel</button></td>

                    <td align="right"><button id="saveAllocation" type="button" >Save</button></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              </form>';


    echo $html;
```

What I need or want the system to do when I click on the `saveAllocation` button is to send the value of the radio button to the database table called `TABLE_ORDERS`.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you take your save button

```
<button id="saveAllocation" type="button" >Save</button>
```

and create a click event for it, you can place an ajax request within that.

```
var saveRadio;
$('#saveAllocation').on("click", function() {
    // Get the selected radio value
    saveRadio = $('input[name="select_driver"]').val();

    $.post("/yourpage.php", {"select_driver":saveRadio}).done(function() {
        // Successful request
    }).fail(function() {
        // Failed request
    }).always(function() {

    });
});
```

using `done()` `fail()` and `always()` functions you can set what you want to happen.

create a page called `yourpage.php` or change the path in the jQuery above.

You'll be able to pick up the value with `$_POST['select_driver']`

Your SQL should look something like

`INSERT INTO table_name(my_column)AS('my_value')`

When using PHP to run SQL. Please be aware of SQL_injection & how to prevent it.
`tep_db_query` appears to be a written function by your PHP application. For inserting values given to you by users please ensure you're using `PDO` or at least `mysqli_` - Otherwise your website *may* be vulnerable to attacks

### NOTICE

This is *FAR* from difficult. We're here to solve problems not do code for you. While I'm happy to help, you should try your best to complete this without having someone practically do it for you.

Let's break down what you needed to do.

1. Find out how to create a jQuery on click event
2. Find out how to get the value of a selected radio input
3. Find out how to use JavaScript to post data to another page (ajax)
4. Find out how to do an INSERT query for MySQL

The first two you can find on Stack Overflow. The first & last you can also find on the jQuery documentation.

Being a good programmer is about problem solving and using your initiative.